# Splitting 1 monitor into many

Tags: windows-10, display

Is there a way to trick windows "splitting" 1 monitor into several monitors?

For example let's say I have a 50" TV, and I would like to make Windows think that four 25" monitors are connected, so that I can run a full screen program on 1 of the "fake" monitors, and still be able to watch the 3 remaining "fake" monitors?

I have tried to search google, and also installed some software, but it only seemed to work in the same way as windows snap assist (I think it's called).

So that the monitor would look something like this:

[image: Split screen]

Comment: It's really bad to accept an answer that you haven't tested. You just said seems right and accepted it. And the answer you accepted suggests that it's close but not what you're asking, and you don't question that at all   and it clearly seems you're not really that serious with your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this: http://www.actualtools.com/virtualdesktops

I read the docs and it seems to be as close as you can get to what you're looking for.

Comment: Proprietary software here...

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about this software? Is it free? How does it work? Have any screen shots to share? With some more detail I think you get some of those upvotes you're missing.

Comment: -1 You haven't stated where it might help him and where it won't. You say it seems to be as close as he can get. well state how it matches what he wants and how it doesn't then. And if it's close but not what he wants then maybe it's better as a comment (and bear in mind that while it's accepted, the answerer hasnt even tested it) He just said "Yeah that seems right ☺ thanks alot[sic]"

Comment: I didn't realize I should copy-paste everything that's on the website from the link.  Seems pretty redundant and I rarely see other people do it.  I will add that the software has a trial period but I don't know how long.  The website doesn't say.  It's $20 after the trial ends.

Comment: 1) Just a link to a product isn't a solution.  Downloading the product might be the 1st step in a solution.  2) Solutions should be definitive, which is hard if you've never actually used the product.  A random Google hit doesn't add much value.  3) Potentially helpful suggestions can be posted as a comment.  4) Link-only answers, especially product recommendations, are not considered answers.  They will attract downvotes and are subject to deletion.  Site standards have changed over time, and low quality posts are not always caught and cleaned up immediately.